# Pandas Conditional Formatting Removed in Excel

Tags: python, excel, pandas

It's my first time formatting an Excel spreadsheet with Python using the Pandas module.

My code is shown below:

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('%s.xlsx'%item,engine='xlsxwriter')
workbook  = writer.book
format1 = workbook.add_format({'bg_color': '#FFC7CE',
                           'font_color': '#9C0006'})

final.to_excel(writer, '%s.xlsx'%item) # Output results to an excel file
#item is simply the name of the excel document.
#final is the name of the data frame I am working with.
worksheet = writer.sheets['%s.xlsx'%item ]
worksheet.conditional_format('A1:CG350', {'type':     'cell',
                                'criteria': 'containing',
                                'value':     'X ',
                                'format':    format1})
writer.save()
```

My code executes just fine. Its when I go to open up the final excel spreadsheet that I run into the following error messages:

[Excel Error Message 1 Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NNzAA.png)

[Excel Error Message 2 Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9NmQC.png)

Basically, Excel forces me to remove the conditional formatting. I am running Python 3 and Excel 2016. Any body have any suggested solutions?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you try this `worksheet.conditional_format('B2:B8', {'type': '3_color_scale'})` just to see if it works without issue?

Comment: possibly you can look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49488326/pandas-to-excel-conditional-formatting-whole-column)

Comment: Unfortunately, @pygo , the above line of code did not work. However, I did not get an error. The formatting was simply not translated. The other page was no further use to me either. Thanks for the attempt though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 'containing' criteria is associated with type 'text' not 'cell'.

If you change that your program will work as expected. Here is an example:

```
import pandas as pd

final = pd.DataFrame({'Data': ['fox red', 'red fox', 'fox red', 'red fox']})

item = 'foo'
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('%s.xlsx'% item, engine='xlsxwriter')

workbook  = writer.book
format1 = workbook.add_format({'bg_color': '#FFC7CE',
                               'font_color': '#9C0006'})

final.to_excel(writer, '%s.xlsx' % item)

worksheet = writer.sheets['%s.xlsx' % item]

worksheet.conditional_format('A1:CG350', {'type':     'text',
                                          'criteria': 'containing',
                                          'value':    'X ',
                                          'format':   format1})

writer.save()
```

Output:

[image]